# Expectation and variance of bivariate skew normal distribution

Tags: statistics, expected-value, variance, bivariate-distributions

I am fitting a bivariate skew normal distribution to a 2D data through the `sn` package in `R`. I get a $2 \times 1$ vector of location and shape parameters $\beta$ and $\alpha$ as well as a $2 \times 2$ scale matrix $\omega$.

In the case of univariate skew normal distribution, I understand the expectation and the variance is given by,

$$
\mu_x = \beta + \omega\delta \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi}}
$$ and

$$
\sigma_x^2 = \omega^2\left(1-\frac{2\delta^2}{\pi}\right)
$$

where

$$
\delta = \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}
$$

and I can compute these quantities when we get the parameters fitting a univariate random variable.

However, here we have bivariate distribution - I have vector quantities and I think we will end up with a vector of expectation and variance, one for each dimension. I am not sure how to compute them through the parameters I got through fitting. Specifically, how do I compute $\delta$ and $\delta^2$ when we have vectors. Please help.

Comment: The expectation is a vector, [but the variance is not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable#Covariance_and_cross-covariance).

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean what we get after fitting, the mean vector $\beta$ and the scale parameter $\omega$ (a $2 \times 2$ matrix) are themselves expectation and covariance and we don't need to explicitly compute them?

Comment: From this thread, I think I need to explicitly compute them:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958120/multivariate-skew-normal-in-r
I am not sure, how though.